# Doctrine 2 Query Like string with quote '

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently I use the Symfony framewrok with doctrine 2, I would like to make a DQL query without going through the symfony Repository,
I had a problem with simple quotes to match with keywords
here is my problem:

```
php bin\console doctrine: query: dql "select a.ann_object from \App\Entity\client c where c.name like '% Jose' An Tales% '"
```

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 74: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'dir'

I have made this request without going through the doctrine setParameters
Do you have an idea how to escape the simple quote?

Comment: Seems the alias for the selected element was wrong: try with `select c.ann_object`  instead of `select a.ann_object`

Comment: `'% Jose' An Tales% '` escape the `'` after Jose with `''` i guess?

Comment: Its work with ' ' ! Thank you Joe